# WordPress Theme folder gets renamed on updating by pre_set_site_transient_update_themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wrote a code for updating my theme. The theme is hosted on my server and every website I add to internet can update it with the update button in the backend.

Currently everything is working as aspected but on updating my theme-folder gets renamed. This will causing some issues e.g. that customizer settings are on default state and so on. I started this code according to this [Recommended Updated Api](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/30/recommended-usage-of-the-updates-api-to-support-the-auto-updates-ui-for-plugins-and-themes-in-wordpress-5-5/)

```
<?php

/**
 * Enqueue Update Check
 * 
 */

function get_theme_version($url)
{

    $response = wp_safe_remote_get($url);

    $obj = json_decode($response['body'], true);
    $themeName = 'mytheme/functions.php';
    $themeArray = ($obj[$themeName]);
    $version = $themeArray['version'];

    return $version;
}

function mytheme_pre_set_site_transient_update_themes( $transient ) {

    // Define your theme details
    $theme_folder_name = get_stylesheet();
    $theme_slug = 'mytheme';

    //get current version
    $theme = wp_get_theme($theme_folder_name); // Get the currently active theme
    $current_version = $theme->get('Version'); // Get the version of the theme

    //get update version
    $updateURL = 'https://myurl/development/mytheme/info.json';
    $remote_version  = get_theme_version($updateURL);
    
    // Query premium/private repo for updates.
    if (version_compare($current_version, $remote_version, '<') ) {
        // Update is available.
        // $update should be an array containing all of the fields in $item below.
        $update = array(
            'theme'        => $theme_slug,
            'new_version'  => $remote_version,
            'url'          => '',
            'package'      => 'https://myurl/development/mytheme.zip',
            'requires'     => '',
            'requires_php' => '',
        );
        $transient->response[$theme_slug] = $update;
    } else {
        // No update is available.
        $item = array(
            'theme'        => $theme_slug,
            'new_version'  => $current_version,
            'url'          => '',
            'package'      => '',
            'requires'     => '',
            'requires_php' => '',
        );
        // Adding the "mock" item to the `no_update` property is required
        // for the enable/disable auto-updates links to correctly appear in UI.
        $transient->no_update[$theme_slug] = $item;
    }
 
    return $transient;
}
 
add_filter( 'pre_set_site_transient_update_themes', 'mytheme_pre_set_site_transient_update_themes' );
```

Comment: I found the issue for this behavior. It is based on the structure of the update zip file. The structure needs to be myplugin.zip/myplugin/files .